Resizing of Pycharm terminal
So basically the issue is with terminal window. I wanted to make it like in some other IDEs(photos below), but found out that there is no way to do it with PyCharm stock settings. Maybe someone knows how to make it the way I want.
The PyCharm terminal looks like the 1st picture, so it is all along the window and I want to look like on thesecond photo, to end by the file section and file section is all over to the bottom of the window.
like that
